# How to list each value of a list which was appended from pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, list

My data has 2000001 datasets. Each data line may have different number of columns. I need to append some columns into a list and then list each element. However, I cannot display each element.

Below is the sample of my data.

```
       0    1        2    3   4         5      6  7        8  9      10  11   12  13
0  FRAM_#    0    0(fs)  CN=   1  PRMRYTGT  14689  H  15449.0  O  1.008 NaN  NaN NaN
1  FRAM_#  100   25(fs)  CN=   1  PRMRYTGT  14689  H  15449.0  O  0.955 NaN  NaN NaN
2  FRAM_#  200   50(fs)  CN=   1  PRMRYTGT  14689  H  15449.0  O  0.993 NaN  NaN NaN
3  FRAM_#  300   75(fs)  CN=   1  PRMRYTGT  14689  H  15449.0  O  0.973 NaN  NaN NaN
4  FRAM_#  400  100(fs)  CN=   1  PRMRYTGT  14689  H  15449.0  O  0.988 NaN  NaN NaN
...
```

And below is the scripts.

```
import pandas as pd

pdf = pd.read_table("pdf.dat",sep="\s+",names=range(14),low_memory=False)

cols = []

for col_i in range(10,14,3):
  cols.append([val for val in df[col_i] if str(val) != 'nan'])

print(type(cols),len(cols))
```

Below is the result.
     2

Apparently, the number of elements in the list is not 2. It should be more than 2000001.

My question is how to display each element? Any further suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show a small sample of your dataframe? Also, your list contains two columns, each of which contain `n` number of rows. To see this, check `len(_list[0])`. I'd avoid calling variables `list`, `dict`, and other builtins

Comment: @C.Nivs Thanks for your comments. Yes, you are right. I should not have put list as variable name. Following your suggestion, I added a small sample in my question. I sincerely appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Here, the scripts have been simplified. I copied codes and modified them.